# Python cgi script how to print links to images from directory

Tags: python, html, image, cgi

I was wondering how you would print links to images from your directory. I tried messing around a bit and so far it doesn't work.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

print('Content-type: text/html\n')

print ('<img src="/~NAME/images/figure_1.png">')
```

error:

```
 CGIWrap encountered an error while attempting to execute this script:

Error Message: No such file or directory
Error Number: 2
```

Comment: when i run the url, i just get and error which i just posted up there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add single quotation.

```
- print (<img src="/~NAME/images/figure_1.png">)
+ print ('<img src="/~NAME/images/figure_1.png">')
```

Comment: What if the error was displayed ? 
if file permision then `chmod 755 FILENAME.cgi`